# [Rails][Searchkick] Reindexing data causes throttle error or timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick, aws-elasticsearch

I am using Rails 5.2 with Searchkick 4.4.2 and an Elasticsearch 7.9 node on AWS.
I am trying to reindex some data in my index, approximately 500k records, and am getting either a 403 throttle error, or a `Faraday::TimeoutError (Net::ReadTimeout with #<TCPSocket:(closed)>)`.
I tried indexing with various methods :

- Object.reindex
- Object.reindex(async: true)
- Object.in_batches with a sleep time inside the block
- Dividing my collection into subsets and indexing each subset individually

What is a good way to reindex a large amount of data ? Are there some parameters that I can change in Searchkick/Elasticsearch to avoid timeouts or throttle errors ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Did you solve your issue @jreid?

Comment: Hi @ilvez, unfortunately I couldn't solve this issue. It seems that Elasticsearch on AWS has some limits that I was not able to change. Instead I used elastic.co and setup a cluster without any problem since.

Comment: We are using elastic.co as well (backend in AWS) and we are having the same issue. Elastic is 7.14.2. On a flipside, we have similar issue with our dev env which runs on local Docker containers. Weird situation & I haven't figured out how to debug the situation really good.